# Yet another try - button click is making my widgets vanish

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget, android-button

When I comment out the line setting the button's OnClickHandler, the widgets in the Activity display fine; when that line is *not* commented out, though, all that displays is the project name in the strip at the top. ???

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttonAuthorizeUsers;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_activity);

        buttonAuthorizeUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAuthorizeUsers);
        //buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this, Configure_Activity.class);  
        OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're absolutely sure that `buttonAuthorizeUsers` is a valid id for a `Button` in your `ondemandandautomatic_activity.xml` layout file?

Comment: What is the error you are getting in logcat?

Comment: aha! That was it, thanks. That's a valid button name, but it's not the button I thought it was. So I was lulled into complacency by the fact that the identifier was recognized (went italic), because it _was_ in the R.java file - however, for another Activity.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the button click that's making the crash. Since setting the listener is what causes the crash, then `buttonAuthorizeUsers` must be null and if you call methods on a null object, you'll get a crash.

Comment: I don't see how it could be null. It's in the corresponding xml file:     <Button
        android:id="@+id/configure_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dip"
        android:text="@string/Configure" />

Comment: @ClayShannon, that's the xml describing the layout. To actually grab a reference to that button in code, you need to findViewById and if the R.id class contains no such id, then the button will be null.

Comment: @ClayShannon notice that in your xml, you gave it the id of configure_button and yet in your code, you try to retrieve it as buttonAuthorizeUsers

Comment: See the auto-answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106659/activity-refuses-to-start/9112158#9112158

I had forgotten to add the second Activity to the Manifest!