# Activity refuses to start

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-intent, android-activity

Now my first Activity is displaying fine, but clicking the button does not bring up the next Activity. I stepped through this code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this, Configure_Activity.class);  
OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure);
}
```

...and it seemed to run fine, but nothing happened, except breaking me into the Debug Perspective, with this verbiage in the Console pane:

```
[2012-02-01 21:01:35 - ddms] execute: returning
[2012-02-01 21:01:35 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:372)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

...any ideas on what might cause this?

Update:
I also tried changing the button click code to this:

```
Intent configure = new  Intent(this, Configure_Activity.class);  
startActivity(configure);
```

...but it makes no difference.

The last line in Console is:

```
[2012-02-01 21:31:46 - ddms] Forwarding client reply 0x166 to [Debugger 8647-->390 active]
```

There is nothing in LogCat...?!

Comment: You tried restarting eclipse???

Comment: have you tried using `adb kill-server` to restart `adb` server which often breaks down after numerous debug operations?

Comment: I'll try restarting again, but I was getting the same problem the last time I ran it (and restarted today). From where exactly do I need to run "kill-server" - from the \tools subdir?

Answer (score 1):

Dang my confounded carcass!

The problem was I had neglected to add the Activity to be started to the Manifest!

Excuse me while I go and berate myself mercilessly.

Actually, I'm just happy to have realized my egregious blunder.